# Android: Button on an WebView-Element (.png-Image)

Tags: android, button, webview

I need to create a floorplan which can be scrolled and zoomed.Some sections of this plan shall be linked to other activities (ie. kitchen). My idea was to lay a simple button on the kitchen-region. With a click on it you can get to the kitchen activity.

Because of scrolling- and zooming-requirement I created a WebView containing my floorplan:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FloorplanActivity"     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewFloorplan"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonKuehltheke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But now I'm not able to lay a button on a specific region on the floorplan. The Button always appears in upper left corner of my floorplan.

MainActivity-Code:

```
    WebView wvFloorplan = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewFloorplan);
    wvFloorplan.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wvFloorplan.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/services_plan.png");
```

What needs to be done to set the button to every postition on my WebView (Floorplan)?

Thx Arne

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be scrolling and zooming this WebView, the coordinates for the kitchen section are going to be dynamic, so positioning a button over it will be difficult.

I would suggest overriding WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading. This way you can use html to create a link to the kitchen activity.

```
wvFloorplan.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("act:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( <kitchen activity> );
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

You will have to write an html wrapper around the image to map parts of your images to different links but now the coordinates will be static. Instead of http urls use Href="act:kitchen"